# Find All FB Users Who 'Like' XYZ Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm trying to use the Facebook Graph API to pull lists of User IDs where said user 'likes' any given page. Ex: a list of User IDs of those who've liked fb page id 10152294138493306& (coca cola's).

Further, is it possible to filter down this list based on age/gender etc?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

https://www.facebook.com/cocacola/likes

Can you see the list of users who liked the page? No, this information is private. And it's the same on the API.

Comment: However, in the graph search I can write 'people who like coca cola' and see a list.

Comment: Right, that's the only way to find this out, but the Graph Search doesn't offer an API yet.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping this would help get me close.. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Thanks for your engagement

Comment: This only allows you to **find** Facebook objects like users, places, pages, events... You can't compose requests. Anyway, it's good to see that you searched on your side.

Comment: So by requests you mean 'find facebook objects (users) who match xyz qualities'? The sample query provided by fb is 'find users whose name is mark' -- https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: This is what I call a simple search for a keyword: "zuck". What I *would call* a "real" request is more than just that: it *would be* `find people who like Coca-Cola` (even if both are "requests").